# Can I shorten the double-bong boot startup on iMac?

Tags: boot, mac

Re: Early 2006 iMac (Intel Core Duo) running Ubuntu 17.04.

When this system boots, it gives the Apple firmware "bong" twice and takes correspondingly longer to boot than I would like. Is there a way to shorten this boot sequence, and make it bong only once? This is *not* a dual boot configuration. It is setup with Ubuntu as the only OS.

Comment: Have you tried Zapping the PRAM?  Hold down `Command+Option+P+R` at boot up until you hear the chime.   I would recommend a few times just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Terrance Why would [resetting the PRAM](https://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2010/12/04/how-when-why-to-reset-the-pram-smc-on-your-mac/#.tnw_QQftWWNE) speed the boot sequence? Are there any inherent dangers that the OP  should be aware of?

Comment: @ElderGeek I used to repair Macs all the time, and zapping or resetting the PRAM can solve many problems.  There is no danger in resetting it as it is actually a recommended troubleshooting step in repairing them.

Comment: @Terrance I've repaired a few Macs in my day as well. As I recall best practices recommends backing up anything critical beforehand.

Comment: @ElderGeek It doesn't erase the hard drive or anything like that.   I repaired them from 99-07 and the first steps in repairing for issues was resetting the PRAM and possibly the SMC (power reset procedure) in correcting TONS of issues.

Comment: @Terrance That's ringing some bells. SMC as well. Sounds like you have the beginnings of an answer here. Why not write one?

Comment: @Terrance  Resetting the PRAM did work to fix this, thanks! After doing that, it powers up with only one bong. Resetting the PRAM is a familiar fix-all for Mac users, but I was thinking the double-boot had something to do with Linux. You should write this up as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Although resetting the PRAM appeared to work on the first try afterwards, it reverted to the double bong behavior after that. So, still looking for a lasting fix.

Comment: You might have a hardware failure then:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/525916?start=0&tstart=0